# Sending alert of new chat message with Codeigniter Email

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, email, chat

I have used  Alasdair Boyd tutorial ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Demu2OfTqI&index=1&list=PL3CB4877FA6E788B3&spfreload=10)) to create a chat service in Codeigniter. Everytime a user enters a new message, this gets submitted to the database and the message quickly appears on the screen with all the others.

Everything works well until the moment I try to introduce codeigniter email feature. When running the send function (which runs codeigniter email), an email is sent however the feature of quickly renovating the messages on screen dissapears.

So, in my view if I use the codeigniter email code it stops running the following line of code in my chat.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function (){get_chat_messages();},2500);
```

(...)

However, I do not understand why. Following I submit all the code. Thank you in advance for all the help.

**My View:**

```
<div id = "chat_viewport"></div>

<div id="chat_input">
<input id = "chat_message" name = "chat_message" type = "text" value = "" tabindex = "1"/>
    <?php echo anchor('email','Say it', array('title'=> 'Send this chat message', 'id'=>'submit_message'));?>
    <div class = "clearer"></div>
</div>
```

**My Controller**

```
<?php
class Email extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){

        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('frontpage');
        }
        $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $data['chat_id'] = "1";
        $this->session->set_userdata('last_chat_message_id_'.$data['chat_id'],0);

        $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $data['first_name'] = $this->User_model->get_name($id );
        $data['main_content'] = 'email';
        $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);

    }

    function ajax_add_chat_message()
    {

        $chat_id = $this->input->post('chat_id');
        $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
        $chat_message_content = $this->input->post('chat_message_content',TRUE);
        $this->send($chat_message_content);
        $this->Email_model->add_chat_messages($chat_id, $user_id, $chat_message_content);

        //grab and return all messages
        echo $this->_get_chat_messages($chat_id);
    }

    function ajax_get_chat_messages(){
        $chat_id = $this->input->post('chat_id');
        echo $this->_get_chat_messages($chat_id);
    }
    function _get_chat_messages ($chat_id){
        $last_chat_message_id = (int)$this->session->userdata('last_chat_message_id_'.$chat_id);
        $chat_messages = $this->Email_model->get_chat_messages ($chat_id,$last_chat_message_id);

        if ($chat_messages->num_rows()>0){

            //store the last chat message id
            $last_chat_message_id = $chat_messages ->row($chat_messages->num_rows() - 1)->chat_message_id;
            $this->session->set_userdata('last_chat_message_id_'.$chat_id,$last_chat_message_id);
            //We have some chat
            $chat_messages_html = '<ul>';

            foreach($chat_messages->result() as $chat_message)
            {
                $li_class = ($this->session->userdata('user_id')==$chat_message->user_id)? 'class = "by_current_user"' : '';
                $chat_messages_html .= '<li ' . $li_class .'>'.'<span class = "chat_message_header">'. $chat_message->chat_message_timestamp .' by '. $chat_message->name . '</span><p class = "message_content">'. $chat_message->chat_message_content.'</p></li>';
            }
            $chat_messages_html .= '</ul>';

            $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $chat_messages_html);

            return json_encode($result);
        }else{
            $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => '');

            return json_encode($result);
            exit();
        }
    }   

    function send($message = null){

                $config = array(
                    'protocol' => 'smtp', 
                    'smtp_host'=> 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                    'smtp_port' => 465,
                    'smtp_user' =>'patient@gmail.com',
                    'smtp_pass' => '12345'
                    );

                    $this->load->library('email',$config);
                    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

                    $this->email->from  ('patient@gmail.com','Mike');
                    $this->email->to ('hospital@gmail.com');
                    $this->email->subject('This is an email test');
                    $this->email->message($message);
                    if($this->email->send())
                    {
                        echo 'Your email was sent.';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                     }

                return false;
            }

}
```

**My MODEL**

```
        <?php
    class Email_model extends CI_Model{

        function add_chat_messages ($chat_id, $user_id, $chat_message_content)
        {
            /* $query_str = "INSERT INTO chat_messages (chat_id, user_id, chat_message_content) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            $this->db->query($query_str, array($chat_id,$user_id, $chat_message_content)); */
            $data = array(
               'chat_id' => $chat_id,
               'user_id' => $user_id ,
               'chat_message_content' => $chat_message_content,);


    $this->db->insert('chat_messages', $data); 

        }

        function get_chat_messages ($chat_id,$last_chat_message_id=0){

            $query_str = "SELECT cm.user_id, cm.chat_message_content, cm.chat_message_id,
                            DATE_FORMAT(cm.create_date,'%D of %M %Y at %H:%i:%s') as chat_message_timestamp,u.name
                            FROM chat_messages cm
                            JOIN person u ON cm.user_id = u.id
                            WHERE cm.chat_id = ?
                            and cm.chat_message_id > ?
                            ORDER BY cm.chat_message_id ASC";


            $result = $this->db->query($query_str,array($chat_id,$last_chat_message_id));
            return $result;

        }

    }
```

**Javascript File Chat.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function (){get_chat_messages();},2500);

        $("input#chat_message").keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which==13){
                $("a#submit_message").click();
                return false;
            }
        });

        $("a#submit_message").click(function(){
            var chat_message_content = $("input#chat_message").val();       
             if(chat_message_content == ""){return false;} 

            $.post(base_url + "email/ajax_add_chat_message",{chat_message_content : chat_message_content, chat_id : chat_id, user_id : user_id}, function(data) {
                if (data.status == 'ok'){
                    var current_content = $("div#chat_viewport").html();
                    $("div#chat_viewport").html(current_content + data.content);
                }else {
                    //there eas an error
                }
            }, "json");

            $("input#chat_message").val(""); 
            return false; 
        });

         function get_chat_messages(){
            $.post(base_url + "email/ajax_get_chat_messages",{chat_id:chat_id}, function(data) {
                if (data.status == 'ok'){
                    var current_content = $("div#chat_viewport").html();
                    $("div#chat_viewport").html(current_content + data.content);
                }else {
                    //there eas an error
                }
            }, "json");
        }
    get_chat_messages();  
});
```

Comment: When I used codeigniter build in SMTP to connect to Gmail or a different SMTP server, it was very slow. I think the email function is delaying the script. Maybe you can sent the email using a cronjob